# Linux: My symbolic links are coming out as broken

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, symlink, steam

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

shopt -s failglob

source="${PWD%/*/*}"
workshop="$source/workshop/content/211820"
mods=$PWD/mods

mkdir -p "$mods" || exit

for pathname in "$workshop"/*/contents*.pak; do
    name=${pathname#"$workshop"/}
    name=${name%/*}-${name#*/}

    ln -s "$PWD/$pathname" "$mods/$name"
done
```

I have a BASH script that scans the `workshop` directory for all files named `contents.pak` within the folders inside. The script then creates a symbolic link to the `mods` directory with the name format: `folder-contents.pak`. The script then repeats this process until there are no more files to create a symbolic link of.

The script itself is working fine, however, all the symbolic links that appear are broken.

The file and folder structure looks about like this:

```
.
├── common
│   └── Server
│       ├── linux
│       │   └── server_software
│       └── mods
├── server.acf
└── workshop
    └── content
        └── 211820
            └── 1234
                └── contents.pak
```

I have tried running `ln -s` with sudo or using absolute paths but the outcome are still broken symbolic links. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: What is `name=${name%/*}-${name#*/}`?

Comment: You are linking to `$PWD/$pathname` which almost certainly is not a correct and existing file name.

Comment: That line is responsible for making the symbolic links output as `foldername-contents.pak`. For example, if the loop found a `contents.pak` file inside a folder called 5678, the symbolic link that would be created would be called `5678-contents.pak`

Comment: Is there anything I can substitute `$PWD/$pathname` with because the script uses variables to create multiple symbolic links until there are none left?

Comment: I have tried creating the symbolic links 1-by-1 using the terminal but the outcome is still a broken symbolic link. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     ln -s "$PWD/$pathname" "$mods/$name"
> ```
>
> What could I be doing wrong?

As `$pathname` is already absolute, it's the prepending of `$PWD/` which does harm; just drop that.

Comment: This has fixed the problem for me. Is it possible for me to merge the `source` and `workshop` variables together?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, as `source` already is inserted in `workshop` and not used thereafter; if you mean whether it's possible to do without the extra `source` variable: of course you can put `${PWD%/*/*}` instead of `$source` into the `workshop` value.